# RPN Program, Object vs Fraction objects: How to solve. JAVA

Tags: java, object, stack

So I'm working on just 1 case right now so I can move onto the bigger picture. I understand there's genius, much better ways to do what I am trying to do, but I'm a student in his first year Java so I don't know mapping, linked lists, anything more than your basic Stack which I wrote the code for rather than used Java's code. **You'll see in my code** that I push the Fraction object if it is not the multiplication operand and pop the two once the operator is found (**I'm not assuming any errors as of right now.)** My issue comes where I need to then multiply the two together. They are and must be Objects in the `push(object x)` When I put them into the stack they are Fractions but pop them as Object objects and cannot use my Fraction.times(Fraction x) method. Any help would be appreciated.

```
public void run() throws java.io.IOException
   {
      String readIn;
      Object op1, op2;
      boolean valid = true;
      Stack myStack = new Stack(MAX_TOKEN);
      Fraction myFract;
      stdin = new Scanner(System.in);
      while(stdin.hasNext() && valid == true)
      {
         readIn = stdin.next();
         myFract = new Fraction(readIn);
         if(!readIn.equals("*"))
         {
            myStack.push(myFract);
         }
         if(readIn.equals("*"))
         {
            op1 = myStack.pop();    // ****THIS IS WHERE I NEED ADVICE/HELP
            op2 = myStack.pop();
         }
         System.out.println(myFract.toString());
      }
   }



public Fraction(String fractString)
   {
      StringTokenizer str = new StringTokenizer(fractString, "(/)");
      numerator = Integer.parseInt(str.nextToken());
      denominator = Integer.parseInt(str.nextToken());
      reduce();
   }

public Fraction times(Fraction z)
   {
      int myNumer = this.numerator * z.numerator;
      int myDenom = this.denominator * z.denominator;

      Fraction newFract = new Fraction("(" + myNumer + "/" + myDenom + ")");
      newFract.reduce();

      return newFract;
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Declare your `op` variables as `Fraction` and use the explicit class casting when popping values from stack:

```
Fraction op1, op2;
...
op1 = (Fraction) myStack.pop();
op2 = (Fraction) myStack.pop();
```

When using explicit casting you must be sure that objects you are trying to cast have `Fraction` type (or its descendants) at runtime, otherwise you get a `ClassCastException`.
More info on class casting can be found [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html).

Comment: So now if I wanted to multiply those two together, say I has an object of type Fraction called total... from there I could do....
    Fraction total;
total = new Fraction(op1.times(op2)); ?
Or is there some other way.

now

Comment: @PlattStudent101, since you already create new `Fraction` instance in the `times` method and return it as a result, the second instance creation is unnecessary. You can simply make an assignment: `Fraction total = op1.times(op2);`.

Comment: @PlattStudent101, and 'newFract.reduce();' in the `times` method seems to be redundant because new Fraction already reduced in the constructor.